# Start playing VLC stream on mobile devices instead of start downloading

Tags: android, streaming, vlc

I have a streaming webside and trying to start streaming on mobile phones/tablets as well.

If I detect a mobile device or tabet I have this code:

```
<script> window.location = "<?php echo $url_of_stream; ?>"; </script>
```

But the video starts downloading instead of playing itself.

Does anyone know what I should do?

I even tried make the `$url."mpeg";` or `$url."m3u8";`

Thanks a lot. (sorry for English)

Comment: Try resetting your app preferences through: `Settings -> Apps -> Overflow Menu -> Reset app preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the MIME type of the binary that you send. You can use 'curl' utility to do so, by using -D option for example to retrieve the complete header. If you send MIME type as binary/octet-stream or application/octet-stream, Android will download the file. Please chose a suitable MIME type, and be very, very thorough with correctness and verbosity of the headers that you send. Attach your header for inspection to the question, if you like.